# Why does my vb.net title bar come out white

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-styles, nonclient-area

For some reason, when I am designing my Windows Application, the form outline/title bar is blue in colour, but when the application runs, it comes out white. Why does it do this and how do I get it to display the normal colour that all windows applications come in? I do not like it white as I feel it makes the application look cheap. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 10 Pro. Picture of the form in designer and while it is running is attached.

I would really appreciate some assistance in this, thank you.

[image: Windows Form]

Comment: You have to realize that it is the VS view that is wrong.  It uses the olden visual style that dates back to Vista.  That's inevitable, Microsoft froze the visual style renderer at Win8.  I'd guess you probably like it because you are too used to the way Win7 looked.  You'll get used to it again.

Comment: It is Windows 10 making the title bar white, not your code. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mine does that too with Windows 10, however when i run an application on a windows 7 computer it will look like it does on the designer and also it will include the Aero theme windows 7 has.

I think its just the way it is because of how the Windows 10 operating system works.

Comment: Thank you, will test it out on Windows 7.

Comment: no worries at all.

Answer (score 0):

The controls implemented from the OS. You need to change properties on the operation system. Maybe this could help:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/change-application-background-color-window-10/167b133e-62f4-4eae-9425-2b9a6019bded